# Adding UICollectionview inside a View Controller

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I've been having trouble trying to add a UICollectionView inside my view Controller. This is the error I'm getting when I try to run my app:

When I run my app Im getting this error: NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-UZJ-6r-Rwt" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UICollectionView.' What would be causing this error?

This is the code I have for the View Controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var names = ["a","d","f","f","h","u","p","s","l","g","y","h","l","k","d"]

var images = [UIImage(named: "title205571580"),UIImage(named: "title193064553"),UIImage(named: "title311505831"),UIImage(named: "title351533554"),UIImage(named: "title528311821"),UIImage(named: "title528311821"),UIImage(named: "title543192229"),UIImage(named: "title544380635"),UIImage(named: "title579492173"),UIImage(named: "title673858816"),UIImage(named: "title713937166"),UIImage(named: "title718520594"),UIImage(named: "title743923696"),UIImage(named: "title800939906"), UIImage(named: "title987804505")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 15
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "uicvcell", for: indexPath) as! UICVCell

    let image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    image.image = images[indexPath.row]

    let name = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

    name.text = names [indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.row == Int("0")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "0", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("1")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "1", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("2")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "2", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("3")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "3", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("4")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "4", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("5")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "5", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("6")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "6", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("7")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "7", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("8")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "8", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("9")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "9", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("10")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "10", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("11")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "11", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("12")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "12", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("13")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "13", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("14")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "14", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("15")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "15", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("16")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "16", sender: nil) }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("17")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "17", sender: nil)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == Int("18")){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "18", sender: nil)



    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're subclassing from `UICollectionViewController`. Is the VC in the storyboard that? Or just a regular UIViewController? If you created it in the storyboard as a UICollectionViewController, then the UICollectionView is already there. If you need to add the UICollectionView, then you probably created a regular UIViewController, and added in the UICollectionView afterwards- which is fine, but then you need to change your source to reflect that.

Comment: Which means:`class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {` should become `class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {`. Also remove `override` from all of the functions, since now you are just implementing the protocol instead of overriding existing functions in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

What is missing is that in your storyboard you have used a UIViewController. Delete that and make sure you use a UICollectionViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your controller is missing it's `collectionView` property. What you need to do is set it as an outlet in your `.storyboard` file. If you want to set it from the code you will need to do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Create your custom collectionView.
let myCollectionView = MyCollectionView()
// Set it as outlet.
collectionView = myCollectionView
}
```